# Complete reducibility, in linear algebra and in topology

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, gn.general-topology, hilbert-spaces

I thought that this is a simple question and asked it at the [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260528/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology), but I now have to elevate it to MathOverflow.

Consider a representation $A(G)$ of a group $G$ in a vector space $\mathbb V$.

In linear algebra, the following two definitions of complete reducibility are in use:

Definition 1

$A(G)$ is completely reducible if it splits into a (finite
or infinite) direct sum of irreducibles.

Definition 2

$A(G)$ is completely reducible if any of its subrepresentations
has a complementary subrepresentation.
$$
~
$$
The definitions are equivalent, because they agree for an irreducible $A(G)$ and also agree for a reducible $A(G)$. The proof of the latter agreement is trivial in finite dimensions, but requires the Zorn lemma in infinite dims.
$$
~
$$
To write down the topological counterparts of these definitions, assume that $\mathbb V$ is a topological vector space (TVS), and recall that the definition of a topological subrepresentation implies the closedness of the subspace wherein it is acting.

Definition 1'

$A(G)$ is topologically completely reducible if it splits into a (finite
or infinite) direct sum of topological irreducibles.

Definition 2'

$A(G)$ is topologically completely reducible if any of its topological subrepresentations
has a complementary topological subrepresentation.
$$
~
$$
In topological spaces, the complementarity is not always guaranteed. (E.g., in a Banach vector space every subspace is complemented iff this space is Hilbert.) Setting this difficulty aside, let us simply assume that the subspaces of our concern have complements.

The two definitions are still equivalent in finite dimensions. This happens because in finite dimensions the notions of algebraic and topological irreducibility coincide (and so do the notions of algebraic and topological reducibility). So the algebraic equivalence entails the topological equivalence.

QUESTION 1

Do topological Definitions 1' and 2' coincide also in *infinite* dimensions?

QUESTION 2

In case they don't, will the situation be mended by making the group $G$ topological?

If not, will the equivalence be warranted by making the TVS $\;\mathbb V $ a Hilbert space?

Comment: How do you change the definition of a subrepresentation when $G$ carries a topology? \\ I think you also need to be clearer about exactly what assumptions you are making; you ask whether certain complements exist, but also postulate that many complements exist.  I guess you mean that you are assuming that all $G$-stable spaces have (possibly non-$G$-stable) complements, and are asking whether the complements can be chosen to be $G$-stable?

Comment: I think the first place to look for questions of this sort is continuous representations of a topological group on a Hilbert space that don't admit *minimal* non-$0$, closed, stable subspaces, like the translation action of $\mathbb R$ on $\operatorname L^2(\mathbb R)$.  I don't know if that representation satisfies Definition 2', though.

Comment: @LSpice As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_subspace)
 , a complemented vector subspace of a Hausdorff space is closed  (the same being true of its complement). Every vector subspace of a Hausdorff space that is not closed is uncomplemented. Also, there exist spaces that possess closed uncomplemented vector subspaces. On the good side, no Hilbert space has a closed uncomplemented subspace because the orthogonal complement of a closed vector subspace is its topological complement. (The latter fact, probably, contains an answer to my last question, is that right?)

Comment: @LSpice It is not clear to me if a topology of G would in any way change my definitions.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear to me how [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1038411) answers [my questions](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1038315). I know that uncomplemented subspaces might or might not exist; it's just not clear to me what you mean by "assume that the subspaces of our concern have complements".  (I made a guess in my comment.)  It is true that all closed subspaces of Hilbert spaces are complemented, but, unless the action of $G$ is unitary, the orthocomplement need not be $G$-stable.

Comment: @LSpice I am not sure if it was clever of me to put the question like this, but yes, this is what I would like to know: assuming that all G-stable spaces have (possibly non-G-stable) complements, can the complements be chosen to be G-stable?

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1038431_405127) is a weaker question. The example from my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1038317_405127) clearly does satisfy Definition 2' (I was being silly), and yet has no irreducible subobjects.

Comment: @LSpice Can you kindly explain to me your last statement? (I am not a mathematician!) You are considering the group of $\mathbb R$ translations applied to $L^2$ functions. How to prove that it satisfies Def 2' ? And why do you say that it has no irreducible subrepresentations?  /How about the translations by $\mathbb N$ numbers? Or by rationals?/ I again apologise for the possible naivtee of my questions. Physicists study group representations as a part of quantum mechanics course, where topology is not even mentioned.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1038469), every $\mathbb R$-stable subspace is complemented because the action of $\mathbb R$ is unitary, so the orthocomplement is $\mathbb R$-stable. What you mention are subgroups of $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R$-stable subspaces of $\operatorname L^2$. An irreducible of $\mathbb R$ is (isomorphic to) a character, and non-$0$ functions transforming by characters of $\mathbb R$ are not $\operatorname L^2$, so there are no irreducible $\mathbb R$-stable subspaces.

Comment: A character is a 1-dim irreducible, correct? How will it look explicitly in this case?
Also, could you please illustrate your last statement with an example? - a function that is transforming by a character of $\mathbb R$ and is not ${\mathbb{L}}^2\,$?

Comment: A continuous character of $\mathbb R$ will look like $\chi_\tau : t \mapsto e^{2\pi i\tau t}$ for some $\tau$.  (I forget whether continuity is automatic.)  Yes, its span is 1D and irreducible, and, in this case, these are the only possible irreducibles.  If $f$ transforms by $\chi_\tau$ and $f(0) \ne 0$, then $\int \lvert f(t)\rvert^2\mathrm dt = \lvert f(0)\rvert^2\int \lvert\chi_\tau(t)\rvert^2\mathrm dt = \lvert f(0)\rvert^2\int 1\mathrm dt$ is infinite if $\tau$ is real (which is the only case we need to consider, since $\mathbb R$ acts unitarily on $\operatorname L^2$).

Comment: @LSpice Your example convinces me that, generally, the two definitions are not equivalent. Are they equivalent in Hilbert spaces, though?

Comment: $\operatorname L^2$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: @LSpice oh no...  So the two definitions are not equivalent even in a Hilbert space?! Then which of the two should we use as "fundamental"? The first one?

Comment: @LSpice Could you also please provide an undergraduate-level reference or two on continuous characters of $\mathbb R$, and how they act on functions?

Comment: I believe, but am not positive, that Definition 1' implies Definition 2', but to deduce from that which is fundamental I could not say.  Definition 1' is the general notion of semisimplicity; I do not know a categorical analogue of Definition 2', but that's probably just ignorance.

Comment: Characters themselves do not act on functions (or, although I suppose you could make them, that's not what I meant to say); rather $\mathbb R$ might act on a function by a character, meaning that $f(s + t) = \chi_\tau(t)f(s)$, with appropriate quantification.  Any undergraduate book on harmonic analysis should discuss this; I would probably think first of Folland, but mostly just because I've taught from it more recently than from Rudin.

Comment: @LSpice Why are you saying that Def 1 ' may imply Def 2 ' ? Have you not just disproved this possibility? Above you wrote that the translation action of $\mathbb R$ on ${\mathbb{L}}^22$ satisfies Def 2 ', but at the same time has no irreducibles. Doesn't the lack of irreducibles make your example incompatible with Def 1' ?

Comment: Yes, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1038764_405127) shows that Definition 2' does not imply Definition 1'.  But I think that Definition 1' implies Definition 2' (or maybe I am missing some subtlety).

Comment: @LSpice  Suppose $f\in {\mathbb{L}}^2$, i.e. $\int |f(s)|^2ds<\infty$. Then $\int |\chi_tf|^2ds=\int |f(s+t)|^2 ds$ $ = \int |f(s+t)|^2 d(s+t)$ $=\int |f(s)|^2 ds < \infty$, wherefrom $ \chi_t f\in {\mathbb{L}}^2$. Or am I missing something? (I guess I am.)

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1038766_405127) is the difference between characters acting on functions, and acting *via* a character.  You have shown:  if $f \in \operatorname L^2$, then $\chi_\tau f \in \operatorname L^2$ for all $\tau \in \mathbb R$.  That is completely true.  My claim is:  if $f(s + t) = \chi_\tau(t)f(s)$ for all $s, t \in \mathbb R$, for some $\tau \in \mathbb R$, then $f \notin \operatorname L^2$ unless $f = 0$.

Comment: @LSpice  Could you please write explicitly how $\chi_\tau (t)$ is acting on $f(s)$? Is it acting as $\chi_\tau(t)\,f(s)=f(\;\exp(2\pi i \tau s)\;)$ ?

Comment: @LSpice When you are writing $f(s+t) = \chi_\tau(t) f(s)$, where is $\tau$ here? How is it acting on $f$? I see only $t$ showing up in $f(t+s)$. I am afraid, I do not understand what it actually means to act *via* a character...

Comment: I think you are overthinking this.  The quantification is:  there is some $\tau$ such that ….  Given that $\tau$, for each $t$ we have that $\chi_\tau(t)$ is a complex number; and for each $s$ we have that $f(s)$ is a complex number.  Then $\chi_\tau(t)f(s)$ is their product, and I am considering what it implies if that is always equal to the complex number $f(s + t)$.  (Namely, in this case, it implies that $f \notin \operatorname L^2$ unless $f \ne 0$.)

Comment: @LSpice So $\chi_\tau(t) f(s) = \exp(2\pi i \tau t) f(s)$ ?

Comment: [Yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1038774_405127).

Comment: @LSpice Sorry to bother you again. Could you please clarify your wording? You said that all closed subspaces of Hilbert spaces are complemented, but, unless the action of G is unitary, the orthocomplement need not be G-stable. Did you mean that the orthocomplement *cannot* be G-stable or *may be not* G-stable? Also, you suggested to seek continuous representations of a topological group on a Hilbert space that don't admit *minimal* non-0, closed, stable subspaces. What did you mean by *minimal*?

Comment: I meant that it is possible (and probably even likely) that the orthocomplement is not $G$-stable, not that it is impossible for it to be $G$-stable.  Minimal in this context is the same as irreducible:  no proper, non-$0$, closed, stable subspaces.

Comment: @LSpice I also have found an extended discussion of this topic here, in case you are interested:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485444/splitting-the-representation-of-mathbbr-on-l2-mathbbr-into-irreducib

Comment: @LSpice I am sorry to get back to this topic. The translation representation of $\mathbb R$ in $L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ does satisfy Def 1 '. It is topologically irreducible and therefore is a direct sum containing only one summand.  It also satisfies Def 2 ' (even though it lack topological irreducibles at all). This way, in application to this representation, the two definitions agree, do they not? And the considered representation does not serve as a counterexample...

Comment: [It](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1040540_405127) is not topologically irreducible.  Consider $\{f \in \operatorname L^2(\mathbb R) \mathrel: \text{$\hat f$ vanishes outside $[0, 1]$}\}$.

Comment: @LSpice Interestingly, in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics they are using Def 2 ' (though in application to topological groups only) : "A representation of a topological group is called completely reducible if every closed invariant subspace has a complementary closed invariant subspace. "
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_topological_group

Comment: @LSpice I think I understand what you mean: for the space $S_1$ of functions vanishing outside [0,1] the Fourier integral becomes a Fourier series, and we indeed get a closed subrepresentation. So our representation *is* topologically reducible. It is not completely reducible in the sense of Def 1 '. Is it in the sense of Def 2' ? Specifically, if I now consider a complementary space $S_2$ comprising functions vanishing in [0,1], i.e. nonvanishing in $(-\infty, 0)\cup(1, \infty)$, will the corresponding subrepresentation be closed?

Comment: The spaces of functions vanishing in (or outside) $[0, 1]$ are not stable under translation; one must instead look at the spaces of functions whose Fourier transforms vanish in (or outside) $[0, 1]$.  These are both closed, and they are indeed complementary.  It may be that similar arguments show that the regular representation of $\mathbb R$ satisfies Definition 2'; I'm not sire.

Comment: @LSpice So, to conclude, the translation representatioin is NOT complete;ly reducible in the sense of Def 1 ', but *is* completely reducible in the sense of Def 2 ', is that right?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1040575_405127), it is definitely not completely reducible in the sense of Definition 1'.  I do not know whether it is completely reducible in the sense of Definition 2', but, if it is, perhaps one could prove it by showing that every submodule is 'like' [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405127/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology#comment1040541_405127).

Comment: @LSpice Speaking of the spaces of functions whose Fourier transforms vanish in (or outside) [0,1], could you kindly explain (or provide a reference) why they are closed?

Comment: I think this comment thread has gone too far afield for MO.  If you would like to ask a question over at [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com) and let me know that you have done so, I would be happy to discuss further there.

Comment: @LSpice I have put my question there. Any comment would be most appreciated.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273183/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-versus-topology-the-example-of-the-tra

Comment: Dear @LSpice, I have now formulated my question as accurately as I could, provided an algebraic proof that Def 1 entails Def 2, and have provided arguments that the algebraic proof can be extended to topological vector spaces. I would be much in your debt if you could have a look at my proof and comment on it
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340895/two-definitions-of-complete-algebraic-reducibility-are-equivalent-by-zorns-lemm